# How can I avoid "Assertion Failed: `id` passed to `findRecord()` has to be non-empty string or number" when refreshing an ember page?

Tags: ember.js

There's this really annoying feature about Ember that I'm not sure how to get around. I may have a url that looks like the following

```
http://{my-blog-name}/posts/view/{some-blogpost-ID}
```

The way I get to this page is by clicking on a link inside of my `{my-blog-name}/posts` page. This works and will display the page as expected. However, if I try to refresh the page, or if I just literally type my `http://{my-blog-name}/posts/view/{some-blogpost-ID}` into my url search box, I will get

```
Assertion Failed: `id` passed to `findRecord()` has to be non-empty string or number
```

Here is how I navigate to the `posts/view/{some-blog-id}` page.

**post.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('post');
    }
});
```

**posts.hbs**

```
<li class="title-list-item">{{#link-to "posts.view" posts}}{{posts.title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
```

**view.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var siteId;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        siteId = params.site_id;
        return this.store.findRecord('post', params.site_id);
    }
});
```

**view.hbs**

```
<div id="Links">
  <h1 id="blog-header-title">My Blog</h1>
  <!--<p>{{!#link-to 'welcome'}} See about me{{!/link-to}}</p>-->
  {{outlet}}
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' }); // This is usually automatic if path undeclared, but declared here to support /index below
  this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('view', {path: '/view/:post_id'});
  });
  this.route('welcome');
}
```

This is really frustrating because it means I can't make a blog post and share the link with a friend. Why does this happen and is there a good way to get around it?

Comment: please include `router.js` file to the question. and also verify when you pass site_id as 123  in link-to helper  is that working ?.`<li class="title-list-item">{{#link-to "posts.view" posts 123}}{{posts.title}}{{/link-to}}</li> `...Moreover this issue will when we are not following ember conventions I believe.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Done. Also added post.js and view.hbs on the off-chance they're helpful. Let me know if you'd like to see more files still. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posts.js route is returning all the posts available, that's the `RecordArray`.

```
<li class="title-list-item">{{#link-to "posts.view" posts}}{{posts.title}}{{/link-to}}</li>
```

so in the above `posts` - refers to single post model or RecordArray of post model ?. if the above is single model then you will receive `params.post_id` in model hook of view.js, currently you are taking `params.site_id` instead of `params.post_id`.

---

Reason for not executing the model hook.
 https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will always have its model hook
>   called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through
>   a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), and a
>   model context is provided (second argument to link-to), then the hook
>   is not executed. If an identifier (such as an id or slug) is provided
>   instead then the model hook will be executed.

Comment: That makes sense. I will try playing with it in the morning and if it turns out to be a RecordArray issue then award best answer.

Comment: +1. The issue was the "site_id" param. That's interesting but I'm curious now why LinkTo always worked even when my parameter was named wrong.

Comment: `{{#link-to "posts.view" posts}}` here as you are providing `posts` model  due to that it will skip executing model hooks and setupController. so in fact it didn't execute model hook you have written. to execute model hook you need to provide id . refer dynamic segments here. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models

Comment: Thanks kumkanillam, I just want to say that I see your answers a lot on the emberjs page and I feel like they're always very helpful.

Comment: Yes. I always refer https://guides.emberjs.com its super useful. Thanks to ember learning team.